# 'Sitting' and 'Standing' are participles?

Tags: meaning, participles, present-participles

He is standing there.

He is sitting on the chair.

'Sitting' and 'standing' are present Participles working here as an adjective?

And are they subjective complement?

Answer (score 1):

No.

Participles in English are often used as adjectives (“the living dead”, “a baked ham”), but they are more commonly used as they are here, with *to be* to create the [continuous tense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_and_progressive_aspects) of verbs.

“He sits” — he typically sits; he characteristically sits; he is just now assuming a seated position.

“He is sitting” — at this moment, he is in a seated position.

(To be clear, “progressive” or “continuous“ is not a tense; it is an *aspect* of a tense, so there is past continuous, present continuous, and so on.)

Comment: And if we wanna show the motion like.....Look, He is standing now( he is in motion for standing)...... Here is also the progressive form....so is there any difference

Comment: I wouldn't go along with everything you say. In "the living dead", "living" fails all the tests for adjectivehood and is best analysed as a verb.

Comment: @BillJ — is “grateful” an adjective?

Comment: Yes.... dictionary says it's an adjective....for example. 'He is grateful'. 'Grateful' here is a Predicative use of adjective.

Comment: @RADS — my question was for BillJ.  He doubted that “living” was an adjective in “the living dead”.  Well, “grateful” is an adjective in “The Grateful Dead”.  But it’s all right; we will get by.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Both are part of the present continuous tense.

They are present participles.

Being a subject complement and being part of the construction of a verb tense are very different.